# Add row under same category

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to have a table according to value from another table so if I choose an item from table 1 it will create a new items row in table 2 and these items will be ordered and every item from the same category will be list under the title of this category.
this is a picture of how the result will be :[image: table]

this is the sample code.

```js
$("#table tr").click(function(){
     
   var row=$('<tr><td><td></tr>>') 
   row.appendTo('#add')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Add item</h1>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Class A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="A">
    <td id="1">A1</td>
    <td id="2">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="A">
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Class B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="B">
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="B">
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="B">
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="B">
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>

</div>
<div>

</div>
<br>
 <table id="add">
 <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Class A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Class B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML? If you can add data attributes to specify the group on each `tr` this becomes much simpler

Comment: Do you mean add like id or class for each tr for items?

Comment: Not quite. I meant [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) as they are much easier to filter by than classes, and can be repeated in the DOM, unlike ids. I've added an answer below with an example of how to use them

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use `data` attributes on each row of the source and destination tables. This way you can determine the group the source row came from so that you can place it in the same group in the destination table.

Also note that I added a class, `.copyable-row`, to each `tr` which is allowed to be cloned to the second table. Your current logic allowed the table headers themselves to be copied.

```js
let $dest = $('#add');

$("#table tr.copyable-row").click(e => {
  let $tr = $(e.currentTarget);
  let group = $tr.data('group');
  let $target = $dest.find(`tr[data-group="${group}"]:last`);
  $tr.clone().insertAfter($target);
});
```

```css
table { 
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}


table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Class A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="copyable-row" data-group="a">
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="copyable-row" data-group="a">
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Class B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="copyable-row" data-group="b">
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="copyable-row" data-group="b">
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="copyable-row" data-group="b">
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="copyable-row" data-group="b">
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="add">
  <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="a">
    <td colspan="2">Class A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="a">
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-group="b">
    <td colspan="2">Class B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="b">
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="b">
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rory Rory McCrossan but actually, I don't  have the second table, the dest table will appear if I click the row and I add the row using function addrow but my issue how can I add the category row  ``` function add_row(className,qty )                                                                                           row = <tr><td>className</td><td>qty</td></tr>  row.appendTo(#add'')